# Is there a DevOps API that can get all the Repos a user has edit permissions to?

Tags: azure-devops

I found the Has Permissions API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/permissions/has-permissions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and the Create Permissions Report API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/permissions-report/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), but these two do not fit the requirements. 
I was wondering if there is an API that can get all the Repos under a project that a user has edit permission to?

Answer (score 0):

The two API you mentioned are normally used to manger the user's global permissions that will affect in all the projects in the organization.

As far as I know, currently, we have no available API or CLI can list all the repositories in a project that an user has the edit permission or other specified permissions.